# Can I raise a Pull Request(bit-bucket) from android studio IDE

Tags: android-studio, bitbucket, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I create a Pull Request from Android Studio?

[image]

I've tried these options but I didn't find any to raise a PR. Have I missed any? Do we have any keyboard shortcuts to raise one?

Kindly help.